# How to compile .bat file using Qt Creator

Tags: qt, batch-file, compilation, mingw

Question: How do I compile a `.bat` file using QtCreator?

More info: specifically, I am trying to install Windows Image Writer and the download only includes source files. The `README.txt` tells me to use QtCreator (I have just installed this for this purpose alone) to compile the file `compile.bat` and I have no clue on how to do this.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you sure you want to **compile a batch file** or do you want to compile something with the batch file `compile.bat`? I can't believe that Qt can compile batch files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The readme text on [this link](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gruemaster/win32-image-writer/0.5/view/head:/README.txt)  (Version 0.5) lists the following requirements:

> Requirements:
>
> 1. MinGW
> 2. Qt for Windows SDK
>
> Short Version:
>
> 1. Install the Qt Full SDK
> 2. Run compile.bat -OR- run qmake and then make in the src folder.
> 3. Compile.bat may be edited to change installation paths of MinGW and QT

=> You don't need Qt Creator (which is included in the SDK), you just need the Qt libraries (which are included in the SDK as well).

According to point 2, you just have to execute the compile.bat (from the command line or by clicking/double-clicking it)

Answer (score 0):

There may be more than one way to do this:

[Bat2exe](http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?lang=en&pid=b2e)

This program will take your batch file and compile it.

Lots of options.
I've used it for years when I've been attempting to hide an administrator password, or to keep someone from 'fixing' a script I've written.

Easy to use.

Comment: If you dont know what bat2exe is then you shouldnt downvote this answer.